# Tracking changes of the pictures library on Windows 10 Mobile devices

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, change-tracking

I am trying to track the changes of the pictures library because I want my app to upload new photos to to a server. To track the changes I followed the MSDN article over here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790201.aspx

If I run my code on my phone (Windows 10 Mobile with Fall Creators Update) it does not work if the pictures are saved to the sd-card. But if remove the sd-card and reboot my phone I can read the changes from the change-tracker. On a Desktop-PC everything works fine.

This is how I enable the background task for the change-tracker:

```
    public async Task Register()
    {
        // Check if your app has access to the background
        var requestStatus = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
        if (!(requestStatus ==
              BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedMayUseActiveRealTimeConnectivity ||
              requestStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedSubjectToSystemPolicy ||
              requestStatus ==
              BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedWithAlwaysOnRealTimeConnectivity ||
              requestStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.AlwaysAllowed))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed to get access to the background");
            return;
        }
        // Build up the trigger to fire when something changes in the pictures library
        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
        builder.Name = "Photo Change Trigger";
        StorageLibrary picturesLib =
            await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
        var picturesTrigger = StorageLibraryContentChangedTrigger.Create(picturesLib);
        // We are registering to be activated in OnBackgroundActivated instead of
        // BackgroundTask.Run; either works, but I prefer the single-process model
        builder.SetTrigger(picturesTrigger);
        BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
    }
```

And this is how I get the changes, which contains the code that does not work:

```
    public async Task GetChanges()
    {
            StorageLibrary picturesLib =
                await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
            StorageLibraryChangeTracker picturesTracker = picturesLib.ChangeTracker;
            picturesTracker.Enable();
            StorageLibraryChangeReader changeReader = picturesTracker.GetChangeReader();
            // if photos are saved on the SD-card the next line does not work
            IReadOnlyList<StorageLibraryChange> changes = await changeReader.ReadBatchAsync();
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Windows 10 Mobile? I already tried to factory reset my device or reformatting my SD-Card, but nothing worked.

Comment: Could you please tell us if you met any error or it just return null when running the code on your phone and the pictures are saved to the SD card?

Based on this article:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790201.aspx, it shows that because SD cards can be removed from the device while it’s powered off, and there’s no journaling on FAT-based file systems, change tracking can’t be guaranteed on an SD card across boot sessions.

Comment: I get an exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080222 Yes the pictures are saved to the SD card, the device is powered on all the time, no reboots involved.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [official blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adamdwilson/2016/10/04/change-tracking-more-betterness/):

> **Calling Enable()**
>
> It’s mentioned above, but just to make sure that it is clear: Apps should call ChangeTracker.Enable() as soon as they start tracking the file system and before every enumeration of the changes. This will ensure that the change tracker is not going to miss changes to the folders included in the library.

So I would suggest to call the `Enable` in the `Register` method as well, right after the task is registered.

Comment: You are right, I should call it right after registering the task. I added this but unfortunately it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Oh, that is very unfortunate... I will try it on my device as well to see if it does work on my side or not.